# Измерение скорости интернета в Kbit (килобитах)

Tags: сервер, скорость

Как я себе это представляю:

1. Измерить кол-во байт между событиями прогресса.
2. Перевести байты в килобиты.
3. Измерить прошедшее время между событиями прогресса.
4. Найти коэффициент времени разделив 1 сек на время между событиями прогресса. Нужно это для того, чтобы если я загрузил 1 килобит за 0,5 секунды, то умножив 1 килобит на коэффициент ( 1 / 0,5 = 2 ) 1 * 2 = 2 килобит\сек.
5. Умножить килобиты на коэффициент.

Что делаю:

1. Установил отдачу серверу 100 килобит.
2. Начинаю загрузку и вычисляю кол-во загруженных байт между событиями прогресса, их 8192 байта.
3. Перевожу байты в килобиты исходя из того, что в байт = 8 бит, килобит = 1000 бит, а значит 1 килобит = 125 байтам. И того 8192 байт = 65.536 килобит.
4. Вычисляю прошедшее время в секундах - 0,003 сек, нахожу коэффициент деля секунду на полученное время - 1 / 0,003 = 333.3.

Ну  а дальше не чего не получается, не сходится. Где я допустил ошибку?

**Добавлено:**

А вообще ошибка в расчетах, но я не пойму где. Файл весит 1,4 Мб, всего загруженных байт:

```
1469855, 1469855 / 1024 / 1024 = 1.4
```

Что соответствует действительности. Время на загрузку ушло 2.186 сек. И получается, что если перевести байты в килобиты:

```
1469855 / 125 = 11758.84
```

И если теперь разделить на время:

```
 11758.84 / 2.186 = 5379.1 (килобит в секунду)
```

Но я то задал скорость 200 Кб\сек, и логи это подтверждают.

Comment: А что собственно не получается то? Вы не до конца дописали кажется. Умножаете коэффициент времени на количество бит, скаченных за это время?

Comment: Вот смотрите - файл весить 1469855 байт, в килобитах это = 1469855 / 125 = 11758.84 Кbit. Время потрачено - 10.147 сек. Скорость отдачи сервера - 100 Кbit/sec. И чтобы узнать скорость скачивания, я делю килобиты на время - 11758.84 / 10.147 = 1158.8 килобит в секунду. Это же неправильно...

Comment: А у Вас там стоит специальный аппаратный комплекс, который строго ограничивает скорость до 100кбит/с?

Но может быть Вы все таки установили скорость 100 кбайт/с? тогда все более-менее сходиться. 1469855/1024 / 10 = 143 кБайт/с.

Comment: @KoVadim: Вы были правы! Скорость в КБ, хотя написано Кб... Сейчас посмотрю что получается при КБ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще то 1 килобит = 1024 бит и надо отдавать серверу не 100 килобит, а как минимум мегабайт. А еще лучше отдавать в течение минуты-двух, а потом померить сколько отдано.

Comment: На сервере у меня большой файл! А скорость отдачи поставил 100 Кbit\sec.
И в килобите 1000 бит. Если хотите спорить, то делайте это с теми, кто придумал так!

Comment: в килобите 1000 бит. А создатели кибибита идут лесом.

А код не работает, потому что временной интервал очень маленький и тут в силу вступает погрешность. Сделайте временной интервал хотя бы 3-5 секунд.

Comment: @shatal, **[Да что вы говорите?][1]**


  [1]: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=Сколько+в+килобите+бит

**upd:** не верить конвертеру яндекса...

Comment: >Вообще то 1 килобит = 1024 бит

вообще-то действительно тысяча

Comment: @DreamChild ну и на старуху проруха, а @shatal надо было писать отдачу не 100 килобит, а 100 килобит/сек.

Comment: Сорри что сразу не уточнил - 100, а сейчас уже 200 килобит в секунду.

Comment: Посмотрел в вики. Там сказано, что 1килобит = 1000 бит, 1 килобайт = 1024 байта(это ГОСТ РФ, так что утверждения 1килобайт = 1000 байт идут лесом). А поэтому, интересные результаты:)

1 килобайт == 1024 байта(ГОСТ!) = 8196 бит (1 байт = 8 бит) = 8.196 килобит == 1.0254 килобайта!!! 2.54% навара после конвертирования (удивительно, но 2.54 - это кол-во сантиметров в дюйме).

Comment: 1 байт = 8 бит, 1 килобит = 1000 бит, 1 килобит разделить на 8 = 125. Отсюда - 1 Килобит = 125 байт, а не 1024!)

Comment: один килобит - это вообще то 128 байт. У Вас в последнем в самом конце ошибка.

Comment: В килобите 1000 бит, а нам нужно узнать, сколько в килобите байт. Но мы знаем, что в байте 8 бит, по этому нам нужно разделить 1000 бит на 8. Это будет 125!
И я смотрю Вы разницы не видите между KB и Kb...

Comment: пусть в ВАшем килобите 1000 бит. да, это 125 байт. Никто не спорит. Но Вы чуть раньше написали 

> Отсюда - 1 Килобит = 125 байт, а не 1024!

где взялось 1024... я не знаю.